# Function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 -x}}$ in series representation.

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Represent the function in *Maclaurin series* and *Taylor series* around point $a$:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 -x}}$$

I find the first few derivatives:

$$f = (1-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$f' = \frac{1.(1-x)^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2}$$

$$f'' = \frac{1.3.(1-x)^{-\frac{5}{2}}}{2.2}$$

$$f''' = \frac{1.3.5.(1-x)^{-\frac{7}{2}}}{2.2.2}$$

so the pattern that I see is:

$$f^{(k)} = \frac{(2k - 1)!!(1-x)^{-\frac{(2k + 1)}{2}}}{2^{k}}$$

For *Maclaurin series* I just set $x$ to $0$ and get:

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n - 1)!!x^n}{2^n n!}$$

However, for *Taylor series* expansion I'm not sure if I should substitute $x$ with $a$ in the derivatives and keep the $(1 - a)^{-\frac{(2k + 1)}{2}}$ term or do something different?

Comment: Yes, of course. And then divide by $n!$ and multiply by (x-a)^n

Comment: @GCab It just seemed very complex and I wasn't sure if it's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
Taylor series is
$$f(x)=f(a)+{\frac {f'(a)}{1!}}(x-a)+{\frac {f''(a)}{2!}}(x-a)^{2}+{\frac {f'''(a)}{3!}}(x-a)^{3}+\cdots .$$

Maclaurin series is 
$$f(x)=f(0)+{\frac {f'(0)}{1!}}(x)+{\frac {f''(0)}{2!}}(x)^{2}+{\frac {f'''(0)}{3!}}(x)^{3}+\cdots .$$